# Файлы с расширением *.x - зачем они нужны?

Tags: c, gcc

В исходниках обнаружил файлы с расширением '.x'. Что это за файлы и для чего они нужны? Компилятор GCC для AVR32. Язык - чистый Си. Вроде как скрипты линкера. Для чего они нужны и что с ними делать?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но это вроде формат DirectX. Я как-то видел модели в таком формате.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Running-Protoize.html

Comment: @gecube натолкнул. Но у меня вроде немного другой случай. Есть инфа, что это скрипты линкера -

.x: default linker script, for “regular” executables.

А что это мне не понятно.

Comment: Ну, у меня тоже весьма размытое представление. Но скрипт для компоновщика - вещь вполне осязаемая и понятная. Насколько я понимаю, это то же самое, что и передача ключей линкеру через командную строку, но когда этих самых ключей много и они нетривиальные (завязаны на какие-либо переменные окружения или макросы) - проще сделать скрипт.<p>
Еще полезная ссылочка http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-1750-ug/p5node5.html

Answer (score 2):

суффикс в имени файла — это всего лишь часть имени.

о содержимом файла (и о том, что с ним «можно делать») судить следует по этому содержимому, а не по имени файла.

для идентификации содержимого файла можно воспользоваться, например, программой `file`:

```
$ file путь.к.файлу
```

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir VG ответил верно, это модели в формате DirectX

Comment: Моя ошибка. Забыл сказать - процессор AVR32. Никаких DirectX нет. Нашел информацию о том, что это скрипты линкера, но что это не знаю. Хочу разобраться из интереса хотябы. Что почитать?

Comment: Да, очень логично писать dx-приложения при помощи gcc. Я не говорю, что это невозможно, но все, что видел для DX обычно было сделано в MSVS.